# Why it does not require internet permission when using Implicit Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android programming and here is my first (and may be silly too). In the Manifest.xml one does not need to write:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

then how does this work?

Comment: You are starting another app. *That app* needs the `INTERNET` permission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission when you need internet connection in your application.

And for explicit intent **(not implicit)** you may not need a permission which is required to do the task. In case of explicit intent, called application required to mention the permission.